# How to change an emr job configuration using c# awssdk api

Tags: emr

I want the output for my reducer to be zipped (preferably gzip).

I am successfully able to launch an EMR job using the c# awssdk but do not know how to change the job confiugration for desired result.

I understand i need to set the following property for the emr job

mapred.output.compress: true

how do i do this in c# code?
also how do I make it produce gzip files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] zipArgs = new [] { "-jobconf", "mapred.output.compress=true"};

 HadoopJarStepConfig config = new StreamingStep()
            .WithInputs()
            .WithOutput()
            .WithMapper()
            .WithReducer()
            .ToHadoopJarStepConfig()
            .WithArgs(zipArgs)
            ;
```

you can find more info at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-output-compression.html